# How can I find out which string in an array appears the most and how many times? Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

So in admin.py I have this code for an action

```
def create_groups ( modeladmin, request, queryset):

    groups = []
    contestants = queryset.count()
    group_amount = 7

    for X in queryset:
        groups.append(groupid)
        X.group = groupid
        X.save()
```

I want to set `group_amount` equal to a number that will allow the amount closest to having an even amount of people in each group. I can't just do `group_amount`/`contestants` because there will be members who appear more than once, so each time they appear, I need to start a new group for them. How can I look in `groups` to find how many times the most repeated string appears?

Comment: Does this code even compile ?

Comment: Not really thats just what I have to start with, I dont know where to go from here

Answer (score 0):

Finding the number of times a value appears in a list is quite easy thanks to the [Collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module. To get the counts into something usable, you can do:

```
contestant_group_counts = dict(Counter(groups))
```

This will give you a dictionary in the form of:

```
{'value': count, 'another_value': count}
```

Which you can leverage to see how many times a contestant appears in a group. Hope that helps you out.